# Rails JSON/JSONP and JBuilder. How to get the correct MIME type / content type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I render the whole record to JSON is works fine for both JSON and JSONP, but I want to customize the response (ideally via JBuilder). But when using JBuilder the MIME type / content-type goes to `application/json` and I need `text/javascript`

The JS code is a standard jquery ajax dataType: 'jsonp'

controller:

```
format.json { render json: @event, callback: params[:callback] }
```

This works and correctly switched content-type depending on if the request has a callback or not, but I want to do a lot of JSON customization. Is there a way to do this via JBuilder?

I tried JPBuilder Gem, but it didn't correct the content-type (it stayed at application/json)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it to work with an `after_filter`. Is there a better way to do this?

controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  after_filter { |controller| handle_jsonp(controller) }

   def show
     ...
     respond_to do |format|
       format.json
       format.html
     end
   end

   private

   def handle_jsonp(controller)
     if controller.params[:callback]
       controller.response['Content-Type'] = 'application/javascript'
       controller.response.body = "/**/#{controller.params[:callback]}(#{controller.response.body})"
     end
   end
end
```

Source: Stephen Paul Suarez's comment on this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=comments)